# Can not stop retrofit sending

Tags: java, android, sockets, retrofit2, okhttp

I use retrofit and OkHttp3 library to send some messages to a server and set its as below :

```
okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();
```

When I want to send a large message(which, for example, it takes about 2 minutes), Retrofit sends my file completely, and after 2 minutes, I get the `TimeOut` message. If I expect to stop sending after 15 seconds and show me the Error message.

Is there a specific item that I must comply with? Please guide me.

Or suggest me a standard way to break this operation after 15 second.

mycode:

```
class RetrofitFactory {
private static final RetrofitFactory INSTANCE = new RetrofitFactory();
public static RetrofitFactory getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}

public OkHttpClient getOkHttp()
{
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(new GzipRequestInterceptor())
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();
    return okClient;
}

public myInterface getlimit()
{
    if (retrofit == null) {
            OkHttpClient okClient = getOkHttp();
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(okClient)
                    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASEURL)
                    .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(objectMapper))
                    .build();
    }

    return retrofit.create(myInterface.class);
}
}
public interface myInterface{
    @POST("api/ReadingApi/Something")
    Call<Something> DoReading(
            @Body List<Something> list,
            @Header("Authorization") String auth);

}


Call<DoReadResult> x = RetrofitFactory.getInstance().getlimit().DoReading(
                            data, "Something");

response = x.execute();
```

**Update:**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
```

Comment: It means that you want cancel request after 15 sec with no result if it takes more time ?

Comment: yes , I want to cancel my request

Comment: What's your version of OkHttpClient library?

Comment: com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0

Answer (score 2):

As you said you are using retrofit , so you need to cancel your call easily with retrofit Call :

```
Call<ResponseBody> call =  
    uploadService.uploadSomething(fileUrl);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {  
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "request success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "request failed");
    }
});
    }

call.cancel();
```

with call.cancel(); you can cancel your request.

See more here :

[Retrofit Cancel Request](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-cancel-requests)

Comment: So when we use `timeout` ? Can you tell me more?

Comment: are you sure that you passed okhttp to retrofit ?

Comment: How to Configure Timeout Settings via OkHttp : https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-customize-network-timeouts

Comment: Yes , i do all of them

Comment: Put that section of your code , i think you did something wrong and can't help while can't see your code.

Comment: What RetrofitFactory.getInstance() return ? i think that you are build Retrofit with default options with RetrofitFactory.getInstance() instead of configured retrofit.

Comment: as I update my question : it's an Instance from `RetrofitFactory`. please see the question again.